# How can I utilise SALT+HASH password saving/checking betwen a flutter(dart) app and a PHP website?

Tags: php, flutter, hash, passwords, salt

I have written a salt/hash password function in my flutter app that works great using PBKDF2. This saves the salt and hash in seperate fields in the mysql db. I have a function that grabs the salt and generates checks the has against the users entered password - so far so good.

I am now writting a PHP based website that uses the same DB, and I want to be able to use the same username:pwd-hash/salt to login to the website.

My problem is that I cant find code in PHP that gives me the same result as the flutter/dart code.

My working flutter code uses the [password_hash](https://pub.dev/documentation/password_hash/latest/) package

```
var generator = new PBKDF2();
var salt = list.first.strPwdSalt; // this is the salt grabbed from DB
var hash = generator.generateKey(pwd, salt, 1000, 32);
```

This outputs a List which I save to the DB, future operations to compare the results work fine (as it is always a List stored as a string in the DB)

I expected the following PHP code to work using [hash_pbkdf2](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.hash-pbkdf2.php) function:

```
$password = "andy";
$iterations = 1000;   
$salt = "wh9wRLd2cZYrdESln1JSzA=="; // Manually grabbed SALT from DB

$hash = hash_pbkdf2("sha256", $password, $salt, $iterations, 32);
echo $hash;
```

This outputs : efeb557dbb1b774333420687411bf8b9

I can not get the above string to convert to a List, or do anything with the List in flutter to get it to the same format.

After many days of googling I am stuck, I hoped this would be a fairly common use-case??

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your Flutter code generates a list of 32 numeric character codes. For the sample password and salt in your question, that list is:

```
[239, 235, 85, 125, 187, 27, 119, 67, 51, 66, 6, 135, 65, 27, 248, 185, 33, 185, 216, 106, 17, 57, 90, 13, 105, 61, 145, 148, 86, 32, 182, 94]
```

PHP's `hash_pbkdf2` function *can* generate the same characters, but you have to tell it to return a binary result:

```
$hash = hash_pbkdf2("sha256", $password, $salt, $iterations, 32, true);
```

(note the last `true` argument).

The binary string this returns matches the string representation of the list you got in your Flutter app, so this might already be enough for you to match against the string value that is stored in your database.

If the string you have stored in your database is not the raw binary string but a hexadecimal representation, you can get that in PHP by passing the result from `hash_pbkdf2` through `bin2hex`:

```
$hex = bin2hex($hash);
// efeb557dbb1b774333420687411bf8b921b9d86a11395a0d693d91945620b65e
```

In case this isn't enough and you need an array of numeric character codes in PHP, you can iterate over the binary string and use the `ord` function to build up an array of character codes from the PHP string:

```
$characters = array();

for ($i=0; $i<strlen($hash); $i++) {
    $characters[] = ord($hash[$i]);
}

print_r($characters);

/*
Array
(
    [0] => 239
    [1] => 235
    [2] => 85
    [3] => 125
    [4] => 187
    [5] => 27
    [6] => 119
    [7] => 67
    [8] => 51
    [9] => 66
    [10] => 6
    [11] => 135
    [12] => 65
    [13] => 27
    [14] => 248
    [15] => 185
    [16] => 33
    [17] => 185
    [18] => 216
    [19] => 106
    [20] => 17
    [21] => 57
    [22] => 90
    [23] => 13
    [24] => 105
    [25] => 61
    [26] => 145
    [27] => 148
    [28] => 86
    [29] => 32
    [30] => 182
    [31] => 94
)
*/
```

Now `$characters` is an array matching the list you got in Flutter exactly.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to respond so fully, I can work with either the binary (by changing the code slightly in the flutter app, or use the array of characters. For other people reading this, there is a typo in the "bin2hash" bit, this should be bin2hex